# Hide Show Section According to server response swift

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, sections

I am developing an app which used table view with multiple section and multiple header view. Is it possible to hide randomly section according to server response, i.e.: I have 6 Multiple cells and header view. I got response from the server which show only 2 sections, 4 section and 6 section. I am trying to achieve this, but didn't get success. Here is my code below:

Code:

```
var allPermissionSection = ["A","B","C","D","E","F"] // default permission 

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return totalSectionTable // total count of showing cell
} 
 
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let modelPermission = mainArrayCheckValidations[0] as! MyAcountModel
    if section == 0 {
        return 1
    }
    //  arraySectionName got from server check index if default section or server reponse index is equal to same then true this continue
    if allPermissionSection[0] == arraySectionName[0] {
            if arrayTblItems.count > 0 {
                return arrayTblItems.count
            }else if modelPermission.phoneNumbersEnabled ==  true {
                return 1
            }
    }
    if allPermissionSection[1] == arraySectionName[1] {
            if arrayTblItemsForElectronic.count > 0 {
                return arrayTblItemsForElectronic.count
            }else if modelPermission.econsentEnabled ==  true {
                return 1
            }
    }
    if allPermissionSection[2] == arraySectionName[2] {
            if arrayTblItemsForEmergnceContact.count > 0 {
                return arrayTblItemsForEmergnceContact.count
            }else if modelPermission.emergencyContactsEnabled ==  true {
                return 1
            }
    }
    return 0
}

 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let modelPermission = mainArrayCheckValidations[0] as! MyAcountModel
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
    if allPermissionSection[0] == arraySectionName[0] {
      //  if indexPath.section == 1 {
            if arrayTblItems.count <= 0 {
                if modelPermission.phoneNumbersEnabled == true{
                    return 40
                }else{
                    return 0
                }
            }
       // }
    }
    if allPermissionSection[1] == arraySectionName[1] {
       // if indexPath.section == 2 {
            if arrayTblItemsForElectronic.count <= 0 {
                if modelPermission.econsentEnabled == true{
                    return 40
                }else{
                    return 0
                }
            }
       // }
    }

    if allPermissionSection[2] == arraySectionName[2] {
       // if indexPath.section == 3 {
            if arrayTblItemsForEmergnceContact.count <= 0 {
                if modelPermission.emergencyContactsEnabled == true{
                    return 40
                }else{
                    return 0
                }
            }
       // }
    }
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: USER_DETAIL_CELL, for: indexPath) as! UserDetail_Cell
        cell.updateWith(mainArrayCheckValidations[indexPath.row], indexPath.row, mainArrayCheckValidations.count, tblCellType)
        return cell
    }
    if allPermissionSection[0] == arraySectionName[0] {
       // if indexPath.section == 1 {
            if arrayTblItems.count > 0 {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: PHONE_CELL, for: indexPath) as! PhoneNumberDetailCell
                cell.updateWith(arrayTblItems[indexPath.row], indexPath.row, arrayTblItems.count, tblCellType)
                return cell
            }else{
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: DEFAULT_CELL, for: indexPath) as! Default_Custom_Cell
                cell.lbl_Name.text = ""
                return cell
            }
        //}
    }
    if allPermissionSection[1] == arraySectionName[1] {
       // if indexPath.section == 2 {
            if arrayTblItemsForElectronic.count > 0 {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CONSTENT_CELL, for: indexPath) as! Constent_Cell
                cell.updateWith(arrayTblItemsForElectronic[indexPath.row], indexPath.row, arrayTblItemsForElectronic.count, tblCellType)
                return cell
            }else{
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: DEFAULT_CELL, for: indexPath) as! Default_Custom_Cell
                cell.lbl_Name.text = ""
                return cell
            }
       // }
    }
    if allPermissionSection[2] == arraySectionName[2] {
      //  if indexPath.section == 3 {
            if arrayTblItemsForEmergnceContact.count > 0 {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: EMERGENCY_CONTACT_CELL, for: indexPath) as! EmergencyCnctCell
                cell.updateWith(arrayTblItemsForEmergnceContact[indexPath.row], indexPath.row, arrayTblItemsForEmergnceContact.count, tblCellType)
                return cell
            }else{
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: DEFAULT_CELL, for: indexPath) as! Default_Custom_Cell
                cell.lbl_Name.text = ""
                return cell
            }
      //  }
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}


 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    if section == 0 {
        let headerView = setupHeaderView(textHeading: " Details")
        return headerView
    }
    if allPermissionSection[0] == arraySectionName[0] {
        //if section == 1 {
            let headerView = setupHeaderView(textHeading: "bers")
            return headerView
       // }
    }
    if allPermissionSection[1] == arraySectionName[1] {
      //  if section == 2 {
            let headerView = setupHeaderView(textHeading: "sent")
            return headerView
       // }
    }
    if allPermissionSection[2] == arraySectionName[2] {
      //  if section == 3 {
            let headerView = setupHeaderView(textHeading: "ontacts")
            return headerView
      //  }
    }
    return UIView()
}

 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if section == 0 {
        return 50
    }
    if allPermissionSection[0] == arraySectionName[0] {
     //   if section == 1 {
            return 50
     //   }
    }
    if allPermissionSection[1] == arraySectionName[1] {
      //  if section == 2 {
            return 50
      //  }
    }
    if allPermissionSection[1] == arraySectionName[1] {
      //  if section == 3 {
            return 50
       // }
    }
    return 0
}

   
  setupHeaderView(textHeading:String) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: tblVw.frame.width, height: 50))
    let headingLbl = UILabel()
    let topLbl = UILabel()
    let botomLbl = UILabel()
    topLbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints =  false
    botomLbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints =  false
    headerView.addSubview(botomLbl)
    headerView.addSubview(topLbl)
    botomLbl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.leadingAnchor).isActive =  true
    botomLbl.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.trailingAnchor).isActive =  true
    botomLbl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:0.5).isActive = true
    botomLbl.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    topLbl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.leadingAnchor).isActive =  true
    topLbl.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.trailingAnchor).isActive =  true
    topLbl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:0.5).isActive = true
    topLbl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    botomLbl.text  = NULL_STRING
    topLbl.text = NULL_STRING
    topLbl.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    botomLbl.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    headingLbl.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: headerView.frame.width, height: headerView.frame.height)
    headingLbl.text = textHeading
    headingLbl.textColor = UIColor(hexString: "587358")
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 245/256, green: 245/256, blue: 245/256, alpha: 0.6)
    headingLbl.textAlignment = .center
    headerView.addSubview(headingLbl)
    return headerView
}
```

So, Here is the my code please let me know if i m doing wrong please correct me

Can someone please explain to me hide or show randomly section,

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
class AllDetailAccount {
var HeaderName: String?
var HeaderDeatil: [Any]?

init(HeaderName: String, HeaderDeatil: [Any]) {
    self.HeaderName = HeaderName
    self.HeaderDeatil = HeaderDeatil
  }
}

class UnitUserDetail: AbstractController {

var allAcountDetailInfo = [AllDetailAccount]()
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return allAcountDetailInfo.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if allAcountDetailInfo[section].HeaderName == "USERDETAIL_STRING" {
        return 1
    }else if allAcountDetailInfo[section].HeaderName == "PHONE_NUMBR_STRING" {
        let modelDate = allAcountDetailInfo[section].HeaderDeatil?[0] as! [PhoneNumber]
        if modelDate.count == 0 {
            return 1
        }
        return modelDate.count
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if allAcountDetailInfo[indexPath.section].HeaderName == "USERDETAIL_STRING" {
        let modelDate = allAcountDetailInfo[indexPath.section].HeaderDeatil![0] as! UnitUserDetailModel
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "USER_DETAIL_CELL", for: indexPath) as! UserDetail_Cell
        cell.updateWith(modelDate, indexPath.row, 0, tblCellType)
        return cell
    }else if  allAcountDetailInfo[indexPath.section].HeaderName == "PHONE_NUMBR_STRING" {
        let modelDate = allAcountDetailInfo[indexPath.section].HeaderDeatil?[0] as! [PhoneNumber]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PHONE_CELL", for: indexPath) as! PhoneNumberDetailCell
        cell.updateWith(modelDate[indexPath.row], indexPath.row, modelDate.count, tblCellType)
        return cell
    }
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DEFAULT_CELL", for: indexPath) as! Default_Custom_Cell
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 40))
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 245/256, green: 245/256, blue: 245/256, alpha: 0.6)
    let lbl = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 15, y: 0, width: view.frame.width - 15, height: 40))
    lbl.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
    lbl.text = allAcountDetailInfo[section].HeaderName
    lbl.textAlignment = .center
    lbl.textColor = UIColor(hexString: "HEADER_LABLE_TEXT_COLOUR")
    let topLbl = UILabel()
    view.addSubview(topLbl)
    topLbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints =  false
    topLbl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive =  true
    topLbl.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive =  true
    topLbl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:0.5).isActive = true
    topLbl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    topLbl.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    topLbl.text = NULL_STRING
    view.addSubview(lbl)
    return view
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 40
   }
}
```